# Multisets in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, set, bigdata

I am working on this problem on CSES,
[Traffic Lights](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1163/):

> There is a street of length  whose positions are numbered 0,1,…,.
> Initially there are no traffic lights, but  sets of traffic lights
> are added to the street one after another.
>
> Your task is to calculate the length of the longest passage without
> traffic lights after each addition.
>
> #### Input
>
> The first input line contains two integers  and : the length of the
> street and the number of sets of traffic lights.
>
> Then, the next line contains n integers <sub>1</sub>,<sub>2</sub>,…,: the position of
> each set of traffic lights. Each position is distinct.
>
> #### Output
>
> Print the length of the longest passage without traffic lights after
> each addition.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - 1 ≤  ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
> - 1 ≤  ≤ 2⋅10<sup>5</sup>
> - 0 <  <
>
> #### Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 8 3
> 3 6 2
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 5 3 3
> ```

So to effectively solve a problem like this, I need a data structure in Python similar to a list but the search and  deletion of elements need to be O(1)
or more like a data structure similar to sets but I need to be able to insert multiple same elements and also preserve order.
My code for the problem is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bisect import bisect_right , insort
x , n = list(map(int  , input().split()))
arr = list(map(int , input().split()))
lens = defaultdict(int)
lens[x] = 1
lights = [0,x]
for ele in arr:
    idx = bisect_right(lights , ele)
    to_be_removed = lights[idx] - lights[idx-1]
    lens[to_be_removed] -= 1
    lens[lights[idx]-ele] += 1
    lens[ele-lights[idx-1]] += 1
    insort(lights , ele)
    print(max([x for x in lens.keys() if lens[x]])  , end =" ")
```

However this code is slow. There is a data structure called multi-sets in c++. However couldn't find a similar data structure in python. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can have a look at `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Especially [Counter staying non-negative](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html?highlight=multiset).

Comment: The `insort(lights , ele)` is an `O(n)` operation. Same with `max` in list being O(n) operation. So overall complexity would still remain `O(n^2)`. You can update max part by maintaining what the previous max was and based on where new part would be inserted. You need both search, insert both to be `log(n)` - so you would need BST/AVL/RB tree to optimize that to make overall complexity `Onlog(n)` for which you can probably use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data structure you have for `lens` is like a multiset, also available as `Counter`. The part of your algorithm that is the bottle neck in terms of time complexity, is this:

```
max([x for x in lens.keys() if lens[x]])
```

This is an operation with linear time complexity, and so it makes the algorithm quadratic.

To improve on that part of the algorithm, I'd suggest using a heap. There is `heapq` which provides a min heap implementation. As you actually need a max heap, you'd just feed it with *negative* lengths.

Secondly, `insort` also has a linear time complexity (although using less time than the `max()` expression above). You can improve on this by using a self-balancing search tree implementation, for which there is no standard library, but there are libraries that provide sorted lists such as [`sortedcontainers`](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/).

Here is how you can adjust your code to implement those two ideas:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

x , n = list(map(int  , input().split()))
arr = list(map(int , input().split()))

lens = defaultdict(int)
lens[x] = 1
lights = SortedList([0, x])  # For faster insertion
heap = [-x]  # Put total width also in a heap
for ele in arr:
    idx = lights.bisect_right(ele)
    to_be_removed = lights[idx] - lights[idx-1]
    lens[to_be_removed] -= 1

    # Add widths to the heap when they are the only occurrences
    right = lights[idx]-ele
    if lens[right] == 0:
        heappush(heap, -right)
    lens[right] += 1

    left = ele-lights[idx-1]
    if lens[left] == 0:
        heappush(heap, -left)
    lens[left] += 1

    # Remove the largest width as long as it no longer represents a segment
    while lens[-heap[0]] == 0:
        heappop(heap)
    
    # The add method is O(logn)
    lights.add(ele)
    # Just output the largest width in the heap
    print(-heap[0], end = " ")
```

Comment: Do we really need a `heapq` here? We can just keep `current_max`(and corresponding indices) and look to the left/right of the new insertion index to see if `current_max` needs to be updated or not

Comment: It is hard to keep the current max, because when the current max is deleted, you don't have a clue which is the next greatest to become the max. That's where the heap comes in.

Comment: Right, when the new index is between the interval of `current_max`, the `current_max` would get reduced, so we would need a heap.

Comment: Unfortunately sorted containers being a third-party library, cannot be used in the solution @trincot

Comment: Also why are we using lights.add() here when we already know which position the element has to be inserted?

Comment: @eyah, `insort` will need to shift *all* values that follow after the insertion point. It is that part that is having a O(n) time complexity. Some sort of a balanced tree implementation will resolve that, and make it O(logn). The source code of sorted containers is on github. They use a kind of B-tree organisation of lists. As there is no standard library for something similar, there is no other solution to either use a third party library or to implement your own balanced search tree solution. What do you expect more from me at this point?